# How to hide HTML Table row using jQuery Variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to hide the **tr** having any **td's** value is **Value1**.

Below code is working fine. But, When I use variable instead of value, the code does not work.

I want it to work using variable.

```
<input type='button' value='hide/show' />
<table id="mytable">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Col1</th>
            <th>Col2</th>
            <th>Col3</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Value1</td>
            <td>Value2</td>
            <td>Value3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Value4</td>
            <td>Value5</td>
            <td>Value6</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>    

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.js"></script>
<script>
var this_value = "Value1";
$('input').click(function()
{
    // Working Fine with Value
    $('td:contains("Value1")').parent().toggle();

    // Not Working with Variable
    // $('td:contains(this_value)').parent().toggle();
});
</script>
```

Comment: Variables aren't automatically replaced for their values in normal strings. You need to use string concatenation or [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
var this_value = "Value1";
$('input').click(function()
{
    $('td:contains('+this_value+')').parent().toggle();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to concatenate that value like `$('td:contains("'+this_value+'")')`:

```js
var this_value = "Value1";
$('input').click(function() {
  // Working Fine with Value
  $('td:contains("'+this_value+'")').parent().toggle();

  // Not Working with Variable
  // $('td:contains(this_value)').parent().toggle();
});
```

```html
<input type='button' value='hide/show' />
<table id="mytable">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Col1</th>
      <th>Col2</th>
      <th>Col3</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Value1</td>
      <td>Value2</td>
      <td>Value3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Value4</td>
      <td>Value5</td>
      <td>Value6</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is that `'td:contains(this_value)'` is one string and the parser does not know that `this_value` is a variable. It is just registered as a part of the string.

As others have mentioned, you need to separate the variable from the string via concatenation or by using a template literal.

ES5 concatenation:

```
'td:contains('+this_value+')'
```

ES6 template literal

```
`td:contains(${this_value})`
```